# Can't upload images in directory with is_uploaded_file() and move_uploaded_file()

Tags: php, upload

I have this form for uploading 2 images

```
    <form enctype="multipart/form-data" action = 'upload_photo.php' method = 'post'>
  Upload your profile picture here<input type = "file" name = "dp"/><br>
  Upload your about me cover here<input type = "file" name = "cover"/></br>
  <button id="upload">Upload Photos</button>
  </form>
```

and I have this php file to actually move the uploaded images to the desired directory

```
   if((is_uploaded_file($_FILES["dp"]["tmp_name"])){
   move_uploaded_file($_FILES["dp"]["tmp_name"],"dp/dp1.jpg");
 }

   if((is_uploaded_file($_FILES["cover"]["tmp_name"])){
   move_uploaded_file($_FILES["cover"]["tmp_name"],"cover/cover1.jpg");
 }
```

this code works for me last week but i can't seem to know why it doesn't work anymore. What code be the problem?

Answer (score 0):

Try using `realpath($_FILES["dp"]["tmp_name"])` .This may help you.

Comment: check you directory permission

Comment: i tried many codes regarding file uploads and even those that run days before no longer works now. i think you are right with the directory permission. but how must i do that in cmd? i tried chmod -Rf 777 FOLDER_PATH but it was unrecognized command